# Combine multiple CASE statements into one and SELECT INTO temp table

Tags: sql-server, syntax-error, insert-into, select-case

I have a query that produces sepearate outputs. I need to combine the SELECT CASE statements into one and then have all outputs inserted into a Temp Table

```
SELECT CASE WHEN #WCV_3.VISIT_1 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), #WCV_3.VISIT_1,110) END
FROM #WCV_3

SELECT CASE WHEN #WCV_3.VISIT_2 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), #WCV_3.VISIT_2,110) END
FROM #WCV_3
```

etc...

```
SELECT CASE WHEN #WCV_3.VISIT_5 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 
 #WCV_3.VISIT_5, 110) END
FROM #WCV_3
```

I've tried

```
SELECT * INTO
 #WCV_4 (this is my new temp table)
FROM
(
SELECT CASE WHEN #WCV_3.VISIT_1 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), #WCV_3.VISIT_1,110) END
FROM #WCV_3
etc... END)
```

But 2 errors occur:

> "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'"

AND

> "Incorrect syntax near ')'"

`

Comment: put `UNION ALL` between this statements.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should look like this :

```
SELECT SomeColumn 
INTO #WCV_4
FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN #WCV_3.VISIT_1 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), #WCV_3.VISIT_1,110) END AS SomeColumn FROM #WCV_3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CASE WHEN #WCV_3.VISIT_2 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), #WCV_3.VISIT_2,110) END AS SomeColumn FROM #WCV_3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CASE WHEN #WCV_3.VISIT_4 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), #WCV_3.VISIT_4, 110) END AS SomeColumn FROM #WCV_3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CASE WHEN #WCV_3.VISIT_5 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), #WCV_3.VISIT_5, 110) END AS SomeColumn FROM #WCV_3
) AS temp
```

`Combines the results of two or more queries into a single result set that includes all the rows that belong to all queries in the union.`

Some more info can find here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx

I have tested this query (without `#WCV_3` table) and it works:

```
SELECT SomeColumn 
INTO #WCV_4
FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN 'a' IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 'a',110) END AS SomeColumn
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CASE WHEN 'a' IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 'a',110) END AS SomeColumn
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CASE WHEN 'a' IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 'a', 110) END AS SomeColumn
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CASE WHEN 'a' IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 'a', 110) END AS SomeColumn
) AS temp
```

Comment: this is getting closer but I get an error that says "No column was specified for column 1 of #WCV_4"

Comment: IT WORKS. however the table this unionall query produces isnt the table format i need (WCV_4 has a structure I defined already) this way the final output will include other columns from my data.

Comment: @darko I will do the unionall statements separately and see what happens.... thanks for your help!!